# How "string::erase" works in cpp?

Tags: c++

When I have for example this next string decleration:

```
std::string myStr("miki");
```

Then I use the next command:

```
myStr.erase(0,1);
```

what exactly happend behind the scene?
Is there any "null terminator" that move one place back as all the letters at the string does?
What exactly happend at the memory when uses `string::erase`?

Comment: Does [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) help?

Comment: you can google for the GCC (libc++) or Clang implementation and find out

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, no that probably doesn't help at all.

Comment: One purpose of the code-formerly-named-stl is that you need not (perhaps should not) care about the implementation.  I think mostly because that implementation is allowed to (and does) change.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "one truth" in C++. Somebody programmed *your implementation* of the standard library. There are other implementations.

If you *really* want to know what happens behind the scenes in the implementation *you* use, fire up your debugger and *step into* the method call.

Comment: While technically true, with the standard mandates it makes it almost certain that `std::string` is implemented as a null terminated `char*`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm sure that's true, but in my view, pressing F11 (in my IDE) and knowing with 100% certainty is better than taking a (very educated) guess.